# Why iterator type of priority_queue is wrong with range constructor?

Tags: c++, gnu

The code is as following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

typedef unordered_map<int,int>::iterator myIt;

class cmpHelper {
    public:
    bool operator()(myIt l, myIt r){return l->second > r->second;}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    unordered_map<int,int> freq_cnt({{3,1},{2,4},{5,2}});

    priority_queue<myIt,vector<myIt>, cmpHelper> h(freq_cnt.begin(), freq_cnt.end());
    //priority_queue<myIt, vector<myIt>, cmpHelper> h;
}
```

and hereunder shows corresponding compiler info

```
 g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Default constructor is OK. And I tried to go through code under directory ***/usr/include/c++/7/bits/***, but still no any idea. Please help point out what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: `freq_cnt.begin()` and `freq_cnt.end()` are iterators to `std::pair<const int, int>`.  They are **not** iterators to `myIt`, which is what your constructor expects.

Comment: And the c++ version of typedef is `using`.

Comment: @DrewDormann
I ran below code
```
 cout << typeid(myIt).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(freq_cnt.begin()).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(freq_cnt.end()).name() << endl;
```
The three are same type as following
```
NSt8__detail14_Node_iteratorISt4pairIKiiELb0ELb0EEE
NSt8__detail14_Node_iteratorISt4pairIKiiELb0ELb0EEE
NSt8__detail14_Node_iteratorISt4pairIKiiELb0ELb0EEE
```

Comment: @TrumanLyng that is correct.  You are trying to initialize a container of `myIt` by passing two `myIt`s to the constructor.  There is no constructor that accepts two elements of the type held.  I am guessing that you wanted to pass two **iterators** to `myIt` (a _begin_ and _end_ iterator), and a `myIt` is not the same as an iterator to a `myIt`.

Comment: @DrewDormann, the following is code of the constructor

`
      template<typename _InputIterator>
        priority_queue(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
                       const _Compare& __x = _Compare(),
                       _Sequence&& __s = _Sequence())
        : c(std::move(__s)), comp(__x)
        {
          __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);
          c.insert(c.end(), __first, __last);
          std::make_heap(c.begin(), c.end(), comp);
        }

`
**freq_cnt.begin()** is passed via **__first**, and **freq_cnt.end()** is via __last.

Comment: @TrumanLyng correct.  `freq_cnt.begin()` is an _iterator_, but it is not the right type of iterator.  It is not an iterator to a `myIt`.The answers here and the compiler error are saying the same thing.

Comment: @DrewDormann, in my above comment, I ran code 
`
cout << typeid(myIt).name() << endl; 
cout << typeid(freq_cnt.begin()).name() << endl;
`

and the output shows **myIt** and **freq_cnt.begin()** are same type.

Comment: @TrumanLyng You are not comparing the right things. Please read the answers you've gotten.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the constructor that takes iterators *dereferences* the iterators to populate the container.

Put the actual iterators in the container instead:

```
std::priority_queue<myIt, vector<myIt>, cmpHelper> h;

for(auto it = freq_cnt.begin(); it != freq_cnt.end(); ++it) {
    h.push(it);
}
```

What you are trying to do would be similar to this:

```
std::priority_queue<myIt, vector<myIt>, cmpHelper> h;

for(auto it = freq_cnt.begin(); it != freq_cnt.end(); ++it) {
    h.push(*it);  // <- NOTE: dereferencing the iterator
}
```

To clarify further. Check this simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using myIt = std::vector<int>::iterator;

    std::vector<int> ints{1, 2, 3};

    myIt beg = ints.begin(); // beg is a `myIt` and *beg is an `int&`
    myIt end = ints.end();

    //std::vector<myIt> iterators(beg, end); // NOK: *beg is NOT a `myIt`, but an `int&`
    std::vector<int> ints_copy(beg, end);    // OK: *beg is an `int&`
}
```

You use iterators to populate containers by *dereferencing* (`*beg` above) the iterators. When dereferencing an iterator, you get the value it *points* at. So, when you dereference an iterator of type `std::vector<int>::iterator` you get a reference to an `int`.

---

If you wrap your iterators in iterators that when dereferenced return the original iterators, you can construct the `priority_queue` using those.

Example:

```cpp
template<class It>
struct iterator_iterator {
    using value_type = It;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = void;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    iterator_iterator(It it) : curr(it) {}

    iterator_iterator& operator++() { ++curr; return *this; }
    iterator_iterator operator++(int) {
        iterator_iterator retval(*this);
        ++curr;
        return retval; 
    }
    
    bool operator==(const iterator_iterator& rhs) const {
        return curr == rhs.curr;
    }

    bool operator!=(const iterator_iterator& rhs) const {
        return curr != rhs.curr;
    }

    // this is used by the priority_queue's contructor:
    It operator*() { return curr; }

private:
    It curr;
};
```

then

```cpp
unordered_map<int, int> freq_cnt({{3, 1}, {2, 4}, {5, 2}});

std::priority_queue<myIt, vector<myIt>, cmpHelper> h(
    iterator_iterator(freq_cnt.begin()),
    iterator_iterator(freq_cnt.end())
);
```

Answer (score 2):

`[freq_cnt.begin(), freq_cnt.end())` is a range of `std::pair<const int, int>` lvalues, not `unordered_map<int,int>::iterator` values.

You can create a range of these iterators with C++20's [`std::ranges::iota_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view):

```cpp
auto its = std::ranges::iota_view{ freq_cnt.begin(), freq_cnt.end() };
priority_queue<myIt,vector<myIt>, cmpHelper> h(its.begin(), its.end());
```

Otherwise, you can default construct the queue and push each element:

```cpp
priority_queue<myIt,vector<myIt>, cmpHelper> h;
for (auto it = freq_cnt.begin(); it != freq_cnt.end(); ++it) {
    h.push_back(it);
}
```

But consider instead having a queue of references:

```cpp
using myValue = typename unordered_map<int,int>::value_type;
using myRef = std::reference_wrapper<myValue>;

class cmpHelper {
    public:
    bool operator()(const myValue& l, const myValue& r){return l.second > r.second;}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    unordered_map<int,int> freq_cnt({{3,1},{2,4},{5,2}});

    priority_queue<myRef,vector<myRef>, cmpHelper> h(freq_cnt.begin(), freq_cnt.end());
}
```